# How unformat ext4 SSD formatted to ntfs

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, ntfs

In my dual boot PC (win 10 - Ubuntu 20.04) I have an 1TB SSD. It was meant as storage for the Ubuntu OS in ext4 Filesystem. Unfortunately by mistake I formatted it with windows to NTFS. The Format was a quick format and I didn't write anything on the drive after the format (thank god I discovered the mistake immediately after it happened). Is there a way to recover the files from this SSD?

Comment: Did you try testdisk? And if deeper search finds files immediately copy to another drive. If you have to resort to photorec, that only recovers files by extension, not full file name. And then sorting & renaming can be a huge task. Best just to reformat & restore from your backup.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk